A is in 1st grade and B is in 2nd grade. Is it offensive to say "A studies in lower grade/class"?
I asked Chatgpt this question and it says "A studies in lower grade/class" is offensive because "lower class or grade" shows derogatory.
But "class" or "grade" here does not refer to social ranking or something but levels of school system.
Or does it want me to say "A studies in smaller grade/class" and "B studies in bigger grade/class"?

This demonstrates the weakness of systems like ChatGPT. Yes, describing a person or thing as 'lower-class' or 'lower-grade' could be derogatory, but saying that A is in a lower class than B at school is not - it's just a statement of fact.

"That's a lesser grade of cooking oil" is a derogatory remark about that particular cooking oil.

We wouldn't say "studies in" but  "is a student in" or simply "is in".

Independent of whether it’s offensive, it can be replaced by A is in an earlier [or even younger] grade than B. To this American’s ear, they sound more idiomatic.

The obvious way to avoid any mention of "lower" is just to say "B is in a higher grade".  Or just mention the numbers "A is in grade 4 and B is in grade 6" Note there are cultural differences between the USA and the UK, since in the UK, you are in a year group, not a grade


A studies in lower grade/class.


A studies in smaller grade/class and B studies in bigger grade/class.

Edit
Listeners are unlikely to be offended.  Nevertheless, we could consider A is in a more junior grade (or 'class').  Somehow I prefer is to studies.
The other phrases smaller class and bigger class refer to the class size (the number of students) and are not suitable.
Also, smaller grade and bigger grade are hardly heard of and are not suitable.

No one would be offended by this. ChatGPT is just wrong.

Thanks, @the-baby-is-you.  I have edited my answer.

+1  You prefer "is in" because it's idiomatic.  Students in a grade don't "study in a grade".

Thanks,@TimR.  Indeed is in grade yields lots of hits; whereas, the study version yields only an invalid return, study in grade school.
